# Latex Fancy Footer only works on even pages

Tags: xetex

I would like to delete fancy header and have fancy footer with only page number (even pages on the left, odd pages on the right). Now it only works on even pages. On odd pages the number is still on the center. Note that table of contents is on the even page but fancy footer doesn not work here also. What is wrong here?

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{grafiki/}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}

% Chapters
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}

\title{
{Title}\\
{\large Text}\\
}
\author{Text}
\date{Text}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Wstęp}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam imperdiet justo facilisis mi egestas semper. Phasellus dictum eleifend facilisis. Integer ac cursus quam, sed consectetur metus. Sed accumsan justo sed vulputate tincidunt. Vivamus facilisis metus vel ipsum venenatis aliquet. Nunc nibh diam, sollicitudin id condimentum sit amet, venenatis vel enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse potenti. Cras et tempus neque, quis porta nisl. Vivamus faucibus convallis orci vel pulvinar. Ut vel velit et velit interdum facilisis sed aliquam ante. Duis a tellus vel lectus mollis lobortis id ac neque. Etiam pellentesque ex sed diam rhoncus, sed fringilla felis bibendum. Curabitur odio risus, mattis vitae neque nec, malesuada pretium neque.

Pellentesque ex metus, porttitor quis lorem nec, mattis lobortis est. Etiam laoreet, leo vitae ornare vulputate, ligula arcu dapibus leo, quis lacinia tortor dolor sed velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin nibh lorem, tempor id turpis vitae, suscipit tristique magna. Fusce nibh velit, pellentesque et ante quis, rhoncus elementum dolor. Maecenas at arcu augue. Integer pretium velit vitae leo eleifend, faucibus hendrerit risus bibendum. In quis dictum ipsum. Curabitur lobortis ultricies tortor id suscipit. Donec dapibus lacus at blandit tempus.

Aenean nec velit at turpis porta suscipit nec sed neque. Mauris turpis tellus, faucibus eu turpis id, vestibulum eleifend purus. Ut nec ex ante. Nam eget enim molestie, porttitor ipsum eu, aliquet mauris. Maecenas vitae tortor luctus, efficitur augue in, vestibulum tellus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla ac enim sit amet metus auctor varius. Vestibulum fermentum enim sem, at pharetra est gravida a.

Fusce euismod a tellus id imperdiet. Maecenas mauris tellus, interdum eget malesuada non, aliquet at ex. Integer odio est, eleifend in tortor ac, lacinia dapibus leo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam dignissim bibendum lectus eget porta. Integer eu nisl venenatis, hendrerit purus eu, sollicitudin lectus. Maecenas convallis efficitur ante, ac auctor ipsum. Ut justo nunc, interdum non ultrices nec, hendrerit quis est. Morbi ullamcorper turpis condimentum elit mollis sollicitudin. Pellentesque eget gravida nisi. Sed a congue mi. Nunc lorem elit, condimentum venenatis est ac, maximus rutrum purus. Pellentesque sapien libero, venenatis in dolor ac, pretium feugiat mauris. Aliquam maximus, lectus sed lobortis sagittis, dui lacus efficitur tortor, a dignissim augue lacus at dui.

Quisque faucibus nibh a ligula elementum vehicula. Praesent blandit aliquam tortor et tempor. Mauris sed mi nec arcu congue tempor eu et felis. Ut in orci consequat, iaculis diam rhoncus, molestie mi. Mauris pellentesque sed lacus non interdum. Duis egestas ipsum odio, eget imperdiet magna rhoncus in. Sed aliquam mollis odio, et accumsan turpis laoreet ut. Phasellus at nibh at eros lacinia gravida eget ac urna. Donec tristique tortor non velit molestie tincidunt. Fusce laoreet tortor eu congue congue. Sed id tempor dolor, sed ultricies arcu. Curabitur sodales accumsan augue, ac volutpat mi varius sed.

\appendix
\chapter{Dodatek A}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam imperdiet justo facilisis mi egestas semper. Phasellus dictum eleifend facilisis. Integer ac cursus quam, sed consectetur metus. Sed accumsan justo sed vulputate tincidunt. Vivamus facilisis metus vel ipsum venenatis aliquet. Nunc nibh diam, sollicitudin id condimentum sit amet, venenatis vel enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse potenti. Cras et tempus neque, quis porta nisl. Vivamus faucibus convallis orci vel pulvinar. Ut vel velit et velit interdum facilisis sed aliquam ante. Duis a tellus vel lectus mollis lobortis id ac neque. Etiam pellentesque ex sed diam rhoncus, sed fringilla felis bibendum. Curabitur odio risus, mattis vitae neque nec, malesuada pretium neque.

Pellentesque ex metus, porttitor quis lorem nec, mattis lobortis est. Etiam laoreet, leo vitae ornare vulputate, ligula arcu dapibus leo, quis lacinia tortor dolor sed velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin nibh lorem, tempor id turpis vitae, suscipit tristique magna. Fusce nibh velit, pellentesque et ante quis, rhoncus elementum dolor. Maecenas at arcu augue. Integer pretium velit vitae leo eleifend, faucibus hendrerit risus bibendum. In quis dictum ipsum. Curabitur lobortis ultricies tortor id suscipit. Donec dapibus lacus at blandit tempus.

Aenean nec velit at turpis porta suscipit nec sed neque. Mauris turpis tellus, faucibus eu turpis id, vestibulum eleifend purus. Ut nec ex ante. Nam eget enim molestie, porttitor ipsum eu, aliquet mauris. Maecenas vitae tortor luctus, efficitur augue in, vestibulum tellus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla ac enim sit amet metus auctor varius. Vestibulum fermentum enim sem, at pharetra est gravida a.

Fusce euismod a tellus id imperdiet. Maecenas mauris tellus, interdum eget malesuada non, aliquet at ex. Integer odio est, eleifend in tortor ac, lacinia dapibus leo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam dignissim bibendum lectus eget porta. Integer eu nisl venenatis, hendrerit purus eu, sollicitudin lectus. Maecenas convallis efficitur ante, ac auctor ipsum. Ut justo nunc, interdum non ultrices nec, hendrerit quis est. Morbi ullamcorper turpis condimentum elit mollis sollicitudin. Pellentesque eget gravida nisi. Sed a congue mi. Nunc lorem elit, condimentum venenatis est ac, maximus rutrum purus. Pellentesque sapien libero, venenatis in dolor ac, pretium feugiat mauris. Aliquam maximus, lectus sed lobortis sagittis, dui lacus efficitur tortor, a dignissim augue lacus at dui.

Quisque faucibus nibh a ligula elementum vehicula. Praesent blandit aliquam tortor et tempor. Mauris sed mi nec arcu congue tempor eu et felis. Ut in orci consequat, iaculis diam rhoncus, molestie mi. Mauris pellentesque sed lacus non interdum. Duis egestas ipsum odio, eget imperdiet magna rhoncus in. Sed aliquam mollis odio, et accumsan turpis laoreet ut. Phasellus at nibh at eros lacinia gravida eget ac urna. Donec tristique tortor non velit molestie tincidunt. Fusce laoreet tortor eu congue congue. Sed id tempor dolor, sed ultricies arcu. Curabitur sodales accumsan augue, ac volutpat mi varius sed.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you load `titlesec`, it will be simpler to load it with option `pagestyles`  and redefine the `plain` pagestyle, adding this code to  your preamble (an not loading `fancyhdr`  which conflicts with `titleps`):

```
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}
```